# Multiple boxplots using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataframe that looks like the one attached, with 6 columns and 1000 rows (tab separated). The column headings (0,30,60,120,240 and 360) are a time series (with 0 representing 0 mins, 30 meaning 30 mins and so on). I'd like to create 6 boxplots corresponding to the columns using ggplot2 in a single plot, keeping in mind that they need to be spaced based on the time difference. It seems I would need to melt the columns, but cant figure out a way to do so. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
        0       30       60       120      240     360
1       1       NA       NA       NA       1       1
2       NA      NA       NA       NA       NA      NA
3       NA      NA       1        1        1       1
4       0.5     0.21     0.15     1        0.38    0.8
5       0.63    1        0.86     0.85     0.94    0.91
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try just using melt?

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(df), aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Senor. That worked with plotting. But what about changing the width of x axis ticks? I'd like 0,30 and 60 to be much closer (since they are only 30 min apart), while the later time points spread out even more as they have a wider time gap between them.

Comment: You'll need to convert `df$variable` to `numeric` (it's a `factor` right now), and then have `aes(..., group=variable)` in ggplot. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805643/ggplot2-add-color-to-boxplot-continuous-value-supplied-to-discrete-scale-er

Comment: @Señor O, how can you sort the boxplots of the dataframe by its median, to plot firts the lowest and on the right the highest?

Comment: @Jeni so this was 7 years ago but I think you'll have to use factors for your x variable and either assign the median rank to their value/level or just name the variable its median.