# Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale 4

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to add colours to my charts but I keep getting the error:

```
continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

This is the code I am using:

```
ggplot(by_team_mean_score1) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = reorder(team1, mean_score1), y = mean_score1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  ggtitle("Mean No. of Home Goals") +
  xlab("Team") +
  ylab("Mean No. Home Goals")
```

Comment: please add sample of your data

Comment: `geom_col(aes(x = reorder(team1, mean_score1), y = mean_score1, group = team, colour = team))` assuming that "team" is a variable in your dataset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add color to boxplot - "Continuous value supplied to discrete scale" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805643/add-color-to-boxplot-continuous-value-supplied-to-discrete-scale-error)